# How to hook an ACF field into the bottom of the "after_shop_loop" section of a Woocommerce category page after pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I found the correct hook of where I want the field to show which is below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'after_shop_loop', 1 );
```

This code works exactly how'd I'd like mine to work but with an ACF text area field. Ideally, I'd like it to show under the pagination. This hook is currently showing above the pagination.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'after_shop_loop', 1 );
function after_shop_loop() {    
    echo "<div class='best-seller'>
            <h3>If you need help or have a question for Customer Service, please visit the <a href='#'>Help Section.</a></h3>
        </div";

}
```

I'd like to create a function to bring in an ACF text area that I've added to the backend for all brands that are coming from WooCommerce taxonomy pages "Brand".

This is what I have so far with no luck. Is there something I'm doing wrong or something special you have to do to get ACF to show on Taxonomy pages? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop',  'after_shop_loop', 1 );

function custom_after_shop_loop() {
$brand_content = get_field('brand_bottom');
if( !empty($brand_content) ) {
echo '<div class="brandbottom">' . $brand_content . '</div>';
 }
}
```

Screenshots from my custom field.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Missing "custom_" in the name of your function and you have to get the current taxonomy term. Tested and works

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop',  'custom_after_shop_loop', 1 );

function custom_after_shop_loop() {

$term = get_queried_object();

$brand_content = get_field('brand_bottom', $term);
if( !empty($brand_content) ) {
echo '<div class="brandbottom">' . $brand_content . '</div>';
 }
}
```